# Jenkins + JenkinsFile + Bourneshell - Step fail

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I updated my plugins and Jenkinsfile recently

Using a common stack of

- Latest version of Jenkins on Ubuntu
- Blue Ocean plugin
- Azure VM Agent plugin
- Pipeline (Jenkinsfile)

I randomly have steps crashing when they are processed on another agent (created by Azure VM plugin).

```
wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file in /tmp/jenkins/workspace/[name of workspace]@tmp/durable-2ae31cde

(JENKINS-48300: if on a laggy filesystem, consider -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300)

script returned exit code -1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you show your tutorial link?

Comment: My tutorial?  Everything has been working for 3 months and it stopped working now following the plugins update.

Comment: This also started happening to me in the last few weeks. I'm still trying to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? It has started happening in my deployment as well pretty recently.

Comment: The underlying issue is likely to be due to a defect in the underlying 'durable-task-plugin'. Jenkins JIRA issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52881 indicates that version 1.25 of this plugin resolves the issue.

Comment: An addendum to my comment above. The Jenkins JIRA issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50379 covers the general case for this issue.

Comment: happens to me as well recently, running jenkins from docker, inside a lightsail aws environment

Comment: Did you ever resolve? This just started happening. All my plugins are up to date, I have plenty of memory and disk space.